# TinyMCE adds closing div

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce, rich-text-editor

Greetings,

I want to know if it is possible to stop tinyMCE from adding closing divs to the text.

For example if I enter this text:

```
<div id="content">
<div id="section-content">
<h3>Our Work</h3>
```

It then becomes this:

```
<div id="content">
<div id="section-content">
<h3>Our Work</h3>
</div>
</div>
```

I do not want those 2 closing divs that are added on to the end.

I tried setting verify_html : false but no luck.

FCK Editor does the same thing so is it possible to do this with that editor as well?

Is this possible?

Thanks,
-Ian

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    cleanup : false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is browser related.
What you want the editor to contain is not valid html. Because of this the browser automatically completes your opening divs (to get valid html; it is not TinyMCE's fault).
As far as i know, this browser behaviour cannot be changed unfortunately!